# Why does up key for retrieving the last command typed sometimes work and sometimes not

Tags: bash

```
$ man cpufreq-aperf
$  cpufreq-aperf
You must be root
```

Then when I type the up key, it gives me `man cpufreq-aperf` instead of `cpufreq-aperf`.

```
$ aaa
No command 'aaa' found, did you mean:
 Command 'aha' from package 'aha' (universe)
 Command 'ara' from package 'ara' (universe)
 Command 'jaaa' from package 'jaaa' (universe)
 Command 'aa' from package 'astronomical-almanac' (universe)
aaa: command not found
```

Then when I type the up key, it gives me `aaa`.

I wonder why there is such difference?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You possibly have `ignorespace` set in `HISTCONTROL`:

> `HISTCONTROL`
>    A colon-separated list of values controlling how commands are saved on the history list.  If the list of values includes ignorespace, lines which begin with a space character  are not saved in the history list.

Or an equivalent rule in `HISTIGNORE`. See [variables used by Bash in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#Bash-Variables).